# python3 soup,replace html element content and save to file

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

how to replace text content of html tag in file and save them to another(some), file ?

Ex. there is a file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p itemprop="someprop">SOME BIG TEXT</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to replace the text "SOME BIG TEXT" in the "p" tag to "ANOTHER BIG TEXT"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html","r") as file:
 fcontent=file.read()
 sp=BeautifulSoup(fcontent,'lxml')
 t='new_text_for_replacement'

 print(sp.replace(sp.find(itemprop="someprop").text,t))
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Does it replace anything or virtually nothing? (Please check if it the first p or not)

Comment: there can be many tags "p" but "itemprop=someprop" is only one

Comment: I've added an answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: You mean using my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `open()` on the output file to write to it.

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
    fcontent = file.read()

sp = BeautifulSoup(fcontent, 'html.parser')

t = 'new_text_for_replacement'

# replace the paragraph using `replace_with` method
sp.find(itemprop='someprop').replace_with(t)

# open another file for writing
with open('output.html', 'w') as fp:
    # write the current soup content
    fp.write(sp.prettify())
```

If you want to replace just the inner content of the paragraph instead of the paragraph element itself, you can set the `.string` property.

```
sp.find(itemprop='someprop').string = t
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies upon on the way you are searching for the criteria try changing the following code:

```
 print(sp.replace(sp.find(itemprop="someprop").text,t))
```

to this:

```
 print(sp.replace(sp.find({"itemprop":"someprop"}).text,t))
```

hopefully, this helps

*(PS: based of your questionI'm assuming that you only have one thing to replace)*